# asp.net 4 jQuery Ajax not working with page method in iis

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, iis

Im normally an MVC chap, so jquery ajax is usually a breeze. Im working on an old webforms project though and cannot get jquery ajax to talk to a webmethod on my local iis. It works on visual studios own web server though.

The jquery is:

```
//Collect data
    var prefs = {
        'pref_1': $('input#pref_1').val(),
        'pref_2': $('input#pref_2').val(),
        'pref_3': $('input#pref_3').val(),
        'pref_4': $('input#pref_4').val()
    }

    //Send data via ajax
    //Uncomment below to send requests
    var loc = window.location.href;
    var substr = loc.split("?");
    $.ajax({
        url:  substr[0] + "/SetUserPreferences",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(prefs),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
```

As you can see I'm taking the location href and searching for the method in there. 
In the index.aspx page I have:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetUserPreferences(string pref_1, string pref_2, string pref_3, string pref_4)
{
    using (lbDataContext dc = new lbDataContext())
    {
        MoreBang_Preference preference = new MoreBang_Preference();
        preference.UserId = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"];
        preference.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
        preference.Preference1 = pref_1;
        preference.Preference2 = pref_2;
        preference.Preference3 = pref_3;
        preference.Preference4 = pref_4;
        dc.MoreBang_Preferences.InsertOnSubmit(preference);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

The site I am working on is an umbraco site, it has

```
<add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

in the httpModules section of the web config and is running in Asp.Net 4 integrated mode. 
 It also has 
`<add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>` 
in the modules tag of the system.webServer section of the web config. 
I am genuinly stumped as to why it isnt working.

Many thanks in advance to those who contribute!

Comment: I know it doesn't really help, but I prefer to use WCF for server-side ajax. I've found it much easy to work with.

Comment: Hi there, thanks, I would normally do something similar but I need access to the Session for this particular routine piece of work.

Comment: If you add AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute attribute, that should give you access to the session from the service. Never tried it myself, but the documentation says it is so.

Comment: Really annoying that this isnt working, thanks simon I shall give that a try.

Comment: sorry, just to be clear ^ is for wcf. There may be something similar for webmethods, I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I changed to using a webservice instead of a page method and posted the session value to a hidden field on the page which was then sent to the web service. Not as clean as id have liked but working now. Frustrating as i have never had problems getting this to work before on iis.

Comment: having same issue, and resolved By same Solution Suggested.. but Any One ever get Solution. is there Something about IIS Configuration?